# DFA with 4 or 5 states

Tags: automata, dfa

Can someone build a DFA with only 4 or 5 states for the language A ?
∑={0,1},
A={z is element of ∑^* | z=uvwxy and u,y are elements of ∑^* and v,w,x are elements of ∑ and vwx has at least one 0-element}. I can only build a DFA with 6 states, but we should build one with 4 or 5 states. Here is my DFA:

[DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbZav.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your language has these properties:

- strings have length at least three
- strings contain at least one 0

We can use the Myhill-Nerode theorem to show that a minimum DFA for this has more than five states:

1. the empty string corresponds to the initial state [e]
2. the string 0 can be followed by (0+1)*(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)* to get a string in the language and is distinct from the empty string. Call the corresponding state [0].
3. the string 1 can be followed by (0+1)*0(0+1)(0+1)* + (0+1)*(0+1)0(0+1)* to get  a string in the language. This is distinct from both 0 and the empty string so it gets a new state, call it [1]
4. the string 00 can be followed by (0+1)*(0+1)(0+1)*, again distinct, [00]
5. the string 01 is indistinguishable from 00
6. the string 10 is indistinguishable from 00 and 01
7. the string 11 can be followed by (0+1)*0(0+1)*, distinct from all previous; call this [11].
8. 000 can be followed by (0+1)*, again distinct. This is the 6th string distinguishable from all shorter strings, meaning that a minimal DFA for your language must have at least six states.